# Re-align object axis to global

Tags: transforms, axis

[image]I somehow my objects got assigned to an alternate grid axis.  I am not sure how to reset it.  I want the object group to spin and rotate on the global XYZ axis gimbal.  Any help on how to reset this would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: The problem is your delta transforms. Prior to 2.8 you could clear them by applying the transforms and in the *Adjust Last Operation* panel check the "clear delta transforms" box. the docs state, that you still can do this – but i can't seem to find it. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html

Comment: It's under the CTRL+A pop up menu in 2.8

Comment: I have tried applying the transforms with no change. It just rotates the sphere. 
 to align with the local axis.  If I apply the transform again it just rotates the sphere again.  

I must be doing something obviously wrong. 

I can not locate the "clear delta transforms" anywhere.

Comment: I found it.  Please post a solution so I can resolve this.